# How to style an element created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style a textbox created with JavaScript by assigning an id to the created element like this:

```
const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
document.getElementById("textBoxForText").appendChild(x);
window.data.appendChild(x);
```

This is my CSS:

```
.textBox {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

In my HTML file i have tried to call the element by its id, but it doesn't work:

```
 <div id="textBoxForText" class = "textBox"></div>
```

How can i solve this issue? I am looking for a solution which avoids using innerHTML if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `class` attribute -

```js
const p =
  document.createElement("p")
  
const t =
  document.createTextNode("this is a styled paragraph")
  
p.setAttribute("class", "textbox") // <--
p.appendChild(t)
document.body.appendChild(p)
```

```css
.textbox {             /* class selector, .textbox */
  padding: 1rem;
  color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Or use the `id` attribute -

```js
const p =
  document.createElement("p")
  
const t =
  document.createTextNode("this is a styled paragraph")
  
p.setAttribute("id", "textbox") // <--
p.appendChild(t)
document.body.appendChild(p)
```

```css
#textbox {           /* id selector, #textbox */
  padding: 1rem;
  color: tomato;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Or use the `style` attribute -

```js
const camelToHyphen = (s = "") =>
  s.replace
    ( /([A-Z])/g
    , (_, m) => `-${m.toLowerCase()}`
    )

const toCss = (o = {}) =>
  Object
    .entries(o)
    .map(([ k, v ]) =>
      `${camelToHyphen(k)}:${v};`
    )
    .join("")

const textbox = {      /* javascript object, textbox */
  padding: "1rem",
  color: "tomato",
  border: "1px solid",
  borderRadius: "5px",
}

const p =
  document.createElement("p")
  
const t =
  document.createTextNode("this is a styled paragraph")
  
p.setAttribute("style", toCss(textbox)) // <-- 
p.appendChild(t)
document.body.appendChild(p)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Its fixed now, I will mark it as an answer to my question.

Comment: If you are to style an object with the `id` attribute, do you do: `h1.setAttribute("id", "heading");` ?

Comment: @MinTae exactly! That will match `#heading` declared in your CSS. I added a `.setAttribute("id",...) example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the script loading before the div with id?
How about loading the script after. Use defer or async

Comment: Yes, the script is a part of something larger and its loading. I have fixed the issue, thanks for the feedback :)